# How can i Rotate and Resize View at a time using Single finger using swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, rotation, resize

I want to rotate and resize view at a time using single finger in swift 3.0 i have found many solution in **objective-c** but i am stuck in convert it in to swift. i have used following code for **Rotating a view**

```
    let panRotateGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.rotateViewPanGesture))
    rotateView?.addGestureRecognizer(panRotateGesture)
    panRotateGesture.require(toFail: panRotateGesture)
    textView?.addSubview(rotateView!)
```

**RotateViewPanGesture Function**

```
func rotateViewPanGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if recognizer.state == .began {

        deltaAngle = atan2(Float(recognizer.location(in: textView).y - textView!.center.y), Float(recognizer.location(in: textView).x - textView!.center.x))
        startTransform = (textView?.transform)!

    } else if recognizer.state == .changed {

        let ang: Float = atan2(Float(recognizer.location(in: textView!.superview).y - textView!.center.y), Float(recognizer.location(in: textView!.superview).x - textView!.center.x))
        let angleDiff: Float = deltaAngle - ang
        textView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(angleDiff))
        textView?.setNeedsDisplay()

    } else if recognizer.state == .ended {

        deltaAngle = atan2(Float(recognizer.location(in: textView).y - textView!.center.y), Float(recognizer.location(in: textView).x - textView!.center.x))
        startTransform = (textView?.transform)!
        textView?.setNeedsDisplay()

    }

}
```

here **textView** is my view which i want to **rotate** and **resize**.

Following is my code for **resizing a view**

```
    func resizeViewPanGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view)

        if let view = recognizer.view {
            view.transform = (textView?.transform.translatedBy(x: translation.x, y: translation.y))!
        }

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: recognizer.view)
    }

}
```

but it not works for me. some one please help me with this, How can i rotate and resize view using single finger at a time in swift 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue using following code. its help me to rotate and resize Image using one finger.

```
 func stickerResizeGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let superview = recognizer.view?.superview

    stickerContainerView = superview

    for element in (superview?.subviews)! {

        if element.accessibilityHint == "Main Image" {
            imgSticker = element as! UIImageView
        }

        if element.accessibilityHint == "Delete" {
            deleteView = element as? UIImageView
        }

        if element.accessibilityHint == "Rotate" {
            rotateView = element as? UIImageView
        }

        if element.accessibilityHint == "Resize" {
            resizeView = element as? UIImageView
        }
    }

    let touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: stickerContainerView?.superview)

    let center = CalculateFunctions.CGRectGetCenter((stickerContainerView?.frame)!)

    if recognizer.state == .began {

        prevPoint = recognizer.location(in: stickerContainerView?.superview)


        //Rotate
        deltaAngle = Float(atan2(touchLocation.y - center.y, touchLocation.x - center.x) - CalculateFunctions.CGAffineTrasformGetAngle(self.startTransform))

        initialBounds = stickerContainerView?.bounds

        initialDistance = CalculateFunctions.CGpointGetDistance(center, point2: touchLocation)
        //stickerContainerView?.setNeedsDisplay()


    } else if recognizer.state == .changed {

        if (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! < CGFloat(100.0) {


            stickerContainerView?.bounds = CGRect(x: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.origin.x)!,
                                                  y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.origin.y)!,
                                                  width: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)!,
                                                  height: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)!)

            imgSticker.frame = CGRect(x: 12,
                                      y: 12,
                                      width: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! - (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                      height: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (resizeView?.frame.height)!)

            resizeView?.frame = CGRect(x: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! - (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                       y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (resizeView?.frame.height)!,
                                       width: (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (resizeView?.frame.height)!)


            rotateView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (rotateView?.frame.height)!,
                                       width: (rotateView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (rotateView?.frame.height)!)

            deleteView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: 0,
                                       width: (deleteView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (deleteView?.frame.height)!)

        } else if (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! < CGFloat(100.0) {

            stickerContainerView?.bounds = CGRect(x: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.origin.x)!,
                                                  y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.origin.y)!,
                                                  width: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)!,
                                                  height: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)!)


            imgSticker.frame = CGRect(x: 12, y: 12,
                                      width: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! - (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                      height: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (resizeView?.frame.height)!)

            resizeView?.frame = CGRect(x: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! - (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                       y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (resizeView?.frame.height)!,
                                       width: (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (resizeView?.frame.height)!)

            rotateView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (rotateView?.frame.height)!,
                                       width: (rotateView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (rotateView?.frame.height)!)

            deleteView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: 0,
                                       width: (deleteView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (deleteView?.frame.height)!)

        } else {

            let point: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: stickerContainerView!.superview)

            let newHeight = (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! + CGFloat(point.y - prevPoint.y)
            let newWidth = (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! + CGFloat(point.y - prevPoint.y)

            if newHeight < CGFloat(100.0) && newWidth < CGFloat(100.0) {

                stickerContainerView?.bounds = CGRect(x: stickerContainerView!.bounds.origin.x,
                                                      y: stickerContainerView!.bounds.origin.y,
                                                      width: 100.0,
                                                      height: 100.0)


            } else {

                stickerContainerView?.bounds = CGRect(x: stickerContainerView!.bounds.origin.x,
                                                      y: stickerContainerView!.bounds.origin.y,
                                                      width: newWidth,
                                                      height: newHeight)

            }


            imgSticker.frame = CGRect(x: 12,
                                      y: 12,
                                      width: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! - (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                      height: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (resizeView?.frame.height)!)

            resizeView?.frame = CGRect(x: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.width)! - (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                       y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - (resizeView?.frame.height)!,
                                       width: (resizeView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (resizeView?.frame.height)!)

            rotateView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: (stickerContainerView?.bounds.size.height)! - 25,
                                       width: (rotateView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (rotateView?.frame.height)!)

            deleteView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                       y: 0,
                                       width: (deleteView?.frame.width)!,
                                       height: (deleteView?.frame.height)!)

            prevPoint = recognizer.location(in: stickerContainerView?.superview)

        }

        // Rotate

        let ang: Float = atan2(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))

        let angleDiff = deltaAngle - ang

        stickerContainerView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(angleDiff))
        stickerContainerView?.setNeedsDisplay()


    } else if recognizer.state == .ended {


        prevPoint = recognizer.location(in: stickerContainerView?.superview)

        //Rotate

        let ang: Float = atan2(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))
        startTransform = (stickerContainerView?.transform)!

        // stickerContainerView?.setNeedsDisplay()


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share a video of this code?